# Can I transfer the queryplan from one server to another?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a fast testserver and a slow production server.

There is no way of just getting a new production server right now. One problem I have is that after some large imports one query on the production server is even slower. I have the impression that each monday things are getting back to normal when the weekly maintainance plan runs.

We recalculated statistics then and rebuild indexes. (The DB is set to "auto recalculate statistics". )

I dont want to execute the maintainance plan on the production server now, because I dont want to put even more load on it.

If the out of sync statistics lead to a different query plan would it be possible to force the production server to use a queryplan from the testserver? Or could I just copy statistics fom test to production? I know I could use hints to force the usage of certain indexes, but the query is quite complex and so thats not feasible.

Comment: Have you tried running the query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reusing a plan from another machine is rarely a good way to go. Make sure that you exhausted all the other options first. Copying the statistics, even if it was possible, would be a terrible idea. Think of how it would affect future work, and make adjusting for changes in database impossible.
Maybe the problem with your query is that it's somehow tuned specifically for that other server. Anyway, here's an article on [Migrating Query Plans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895281.aspx).

Comment: >> Reusing a plan from another machine is rarely a good way to go. Agreed: I promis I will not try this at home.